# how to filter Defect search by active projects in Rally using Web API

Tags: rally

I built a custom search tool to allow searching Rally via the Web API from other applications and I've run into an issue.  Right now I am allowing defects to be searched but I noticed that defects are coming back in the search results that are related to a project that is closed.  I need to filter these out.  I am wondering if there is a way to access attributes on a referenced object when querying another object, for example, if I have a query to search for defects where the name contains some text, such as https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect?query=(Name contains "keyword"), can I include something in that query to say that I only want defects for open projects by using the Project attribute on Defect, such as Project.State equals "Open".  Basically I'm wondering if there is a way to do it in one query in an OData-ish format. Or as an alternative, if I separately query for a list of all open projects, could I add conditions to the query to say something like (Name contains "keyword") AND (ProjectId = ... OR ProjectId OR ...)?  Any thoughts or suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query for defects (or any other work item types) is not expected to  return items from closed projects. WS API queries do not search closed projects.

- Created a defect in a project. It happens to have FormattedID DE529
- Tested (FormattedID = DE529) in WS API.

This json was returned:

```
{
QueryResult: {
_rallyAPIMajor: "2",
_rallyAPIMinor: "0",
Errors: [ ],
Warnings: [ ],
TotalResultCount: 1,
StartIndex: 1,
PageSize: 20,
Results: [
{
_rallyAPIMajor: "2",
_rallyAPIMinor: "0",
_ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect/36182496495",
_refObjectUUID: "aa35839a-5e49-44c6-8be7-2fb17bbd91bf",
_refObjectName: "bad defect",
_type: "Defect"
}
]
}
}
```

- Closed the project. Ran the same query:

No result:

```
{
QueryResult: {
_rallyAPIMajor: "2",
_rallyAPIMinor: "0",
Errors: [ ],
Warnings: [ ],
TotalResultCount: 0,
StartIndex: 1,
PageSize: 20,
Results: [ ]
}
}
```

Also, it is not possible to query Projects by State. This query will return 0 results even when there are closed projects in the workspace 1234:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/12345&query=(State = Closed)
```

Project names in Rally do not have to be unique. Identifying a project by Name may produce a misleading result in a corner case when you have two projects with the same name(one is Open, the other is Closed).